# How do I pull row values based on category into separate columns in teradata sql?

Tags: sql, pivot, teradata, teradatasql

[image: Source Table]
[image: Result]

I tried doing aggregation but it still results in multiple rows for each id. I would like to write a query to get data as in result table (2nd) from the source table (1). AmtCategory 1->AmtPaid, 2-AmtReturned, 3->Fees

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to pivot the dataset like so:

```
select userid,
    coalesce(max(case when amtcategory = 1 then amttransac end), 0) amtpaid,
    coalesce(max(case when amtcategory = 2 then amttransac end), 0) amtreturned,
    coalesce(max(case when amtcategory = 3 then amttransac end), 0€ fees
from mytable
group by userid
```